# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError Shown in spite of having respective .class files in the directory

Tags: java, class, package, runtime-error, noclassdeffounderror

let's say in a package using **Java** we are using 4 files.
First one say *StudentModel.java* ,second one say *studentView.java*,the third *studentController.java* and fourth *studentMain.java*.

Then I compiled these files in these order in one line  **studentModel.java** , **studentView.java** , **sudentController.java** and **studentMain.java**.

But I received the following runtime error while running this command :

```
java studentMain
```

in spite of having the respective .class files in the folder :

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: studentMain (wrong name: student/studentMain)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:803)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
```

I am including the picture of terminal while executing the

```
java studentMain
```

command.

[RunTime Error Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2sR01.png)

[RunTime Error while setting the classpath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZFyN.png)

Comment: you need to run the command from the package or give full path for the class name.

Comment: I am running the command from package itself

Comment: Try ```$java student.studentMain```. No slashes. You should give the fully qualified name of the main class iirc.

Comment: I tried `java student.studentMain` but it's giving the same error : 
`Error: Could not find or load main class student.studentMain` @JornVernee

Comment: You need to set the classpath too. If you don't put the classpath, ```java``` will look for a subfolder called ```student``` in the current folder, in which to find ```studentMain``` (because the default classpath is the current folder). Alternatively, you could ```cd``` one folder up and try again.

Comment: @JornVernee I tried by setting the classpath and by going one directory up in the hierarchy both gave the same error. You can cross-check from the image of the terminal I entered.

Comment: @JornVernee This was the error given while trying to execute from terminal by going one folder up by `cd ..`

`aneek@aneek-Latitude-E5420:~/file/oop/asg4/student$ cd ..
aneek@aneek-Latitude-E5420:~/file/oop/asg4$ java studentMain -classpath /home/aneek/file/oop/asg4/student/
Error: Could not find or load main class studentMain
aneek@aneek-Latitude-E5420:~/file/oop/asg4$ java studentMain -classpath /home/aneek/file/oop/asg4/
Error: Could not find or load main class studentMain
aneek@aneek-Latitude-E5420:~/file/oop/asg4$`

Comment: can you share `student/studentMain` for us?

Comment: Try ```java -cp "/home/aneek/file/oop/asg4" student.studentMain```. Note that ```-cp``` is the same as ```-classpath```. One way or another, you always need to put ```student.studentMain```, the fully qualified name of the main class.

Comment: Thanks a lot @JornVernee it worked.